# SQL Server Process Id Lock Error

Tags: sql-server

> This is Error.I am getting while inserting the record to Database Save

**Transaction (Process ID 78) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim**. Rerun the transaction.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information
about the error and where it originated in the code.

Can any one tell me why SQL is showing this kind of Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is being shown because someone else was locking the records in which you were trying to write with your transaction, and you were trying to lock records the other transaction was trying to write to.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/16/sql-server-fix-error-1205-transaction-process-id-was-deadlocked-on-resources-with-another-process-and-has-been-chosen-as-the-deadlock-victim-rerun-the-transaction/

There's a good explanation on that url.